# Additional options to print to pdf using chrome headless options

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, command

I am using the command line in Windows to print a PDF using Google Chrome with the headless options Print to PDF. I want to know how can I use the other options available as the margins and pages size or even orientation. I notice the options are available in https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page#method-printToPDF

but base on this question, it seems doesnt work https://superuser.com/questions/1281309/how-can-i-print-a-webpage-in-landscape-mode-using-headless-chromium-on-the-comma

Has anyone use any of the options available and what is the correct sintaxis as the code below generates the pdf but ignores page size?

```
chrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=C:\\Spotfire_Export\\'+filename+'.pdf --paperWidth=15 '+tempFolder+filename+'.html
```

Comment: I am currently encountering the same issue. It seems Chrome headless only supports PDF conversion of webpage in Portrait mode and there aren't any command line options to specify, paper size, format or orientation.

Answer (score 6):

I also had the same issue and found the same links mentioned before.

I'm generating pages with PHP and running google-chrome via `exec`.

Then I found [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size) and tried on my case and it worked well.

Here is the code which I added in my CSS.

```
@page {
    size: A4 landscape;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I hope that this helps someone.